# order by sum of columns on a per row basis in sequel

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following columns: `comments_html,fb_total,google_plus_one,pinterest,linked_in`

when added together for a particular row they make up the value total_social on that given row.

the table is `npt_articles`

How do I order by the aggregate value `total_social`

I'm also using the sequel gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your quetsion... but this may give you an idea:

```
SELECT (comments_html+fb_total+google_plus_one+pinterest+linked_in) as 'total_social', *
FROM npt_articles
WHERE <<something>>
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: close enough, I did ` SELECT *,(comments_html+fb_total+google_plus_one+pinterest+linked_in) as total_social` at the beginning and `ORDER BY total_social DESC` at the end